# Theming custom entity created with Entity API: accessing entity's fields in template file

Tags: theming, entities

First of all let me say that this is my first project in Drupal and I am still confused, I apologize if my question is stupid.

I created a custom entity in Drupal 7 using Entity API. The custom entity represents a golf course.

I used this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/series/build-your-own-custom-entities-in-drupal/
Then I tried to add a custom theme, to do so I followed this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1238606

My callback function looks like this:

```
function view_my_entity($id) {
  $entities = entity_load('my_entity_type', array($id));
  $entity = $courses[$id];
  drupal_set_title($entity->name);
  $output = entity_view('my_entity_type', array($entity));
  $output += array(
    '#theme'     => 'my_theme',
    '#element'   => $output,
    '#view_mode' => 'full',
    '#language'  => LANGUAGE_NONE,
  );
  return $output;
}
```

And this is my `hook_theme()`:

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_theme' => array(
      'variables' => array('element' => null),
      'template' => 'my_template',
    ),
  );
}
```

The problem is that in `my_template.tpl.php` I can only access the golf course variables this way (in this example I will access the address):

```
render($element['my_entity_type']['The Name of my Entity']['address']['#markup'])
```

As you can see, in order to access the address I have to use 'The Lakes Golf Club', (which is the name of the currently displayed golf course), as a key, but obviously that name is going to change every time I display a different golf course, so my question is:

How can I access the golf course attributes without having to use the golf course name as a key?

**EDIT**

the docs for entity_view() (http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/7) say the following:

> Return value
>
> The renderable array, keyed by the entity type and by entity
>   identifiers, for which the entity name is used if existing - see
>   entity_id(). If there is no information on how to view an entity,
>   FALSE is returned.

So how do I avoid that the array is keyed by the name of the entity? If it was keyed by the id it would be OK because I have the `$id` variable in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved by including this snippet at the beginning of your template file:

```
// my_template.tpl.php
<?php
$keys = array_keys($element['my_entity_type']);
$my_entity_name = $keys[0];
$my_entity = $element['my_entity_type'][$my_entity_name];
?>
```

Now you can easily print values like so:

```
<?php print render($my_entity['address']['#markup']); ?>
```